# Empty value clause for a string not working

Tags: php, string

I am trying to get value with ajax and the values are in form of string, but the problem is when I'm trying to use a condition of if value empty then return this or else do that

My code is

```
if (empty($title) || empty($thumbnail) || empty($link))
{
    echo "404";
}
else
{
    some custom line
}
```

My problem is that a 404 is returned even if the value of any one of them (`title`, `thumbnail`, or `link`) is not empty. Can any one point me where I am wrong?

Here's how I am getting value from ajax:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']);
$thumbnail = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['thumbnail']);
$link = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['link']);
```

Comment: Are you sure each of those is getting populated? Does your if() statement work if you test with hard-coded strings?

Comment: yes it is working with hard coded. i dnt knw what is the problem istead of empty is tried to use $title=' ' then also it not working

Comment: Should you not use `&&` instead of `||`? Or I'm getting wrong the part "but even if the value of any one of them title or thumbnail or link is not empty then also 404 is returned" ?

Comment: I'm with @Havelock, I think you want && instead of ||.

Comment: i am not using and (&&) i m using or (||) and even if i use only one then also not working, its working with hard coded but not with ajax

Comment: @ctrahey pointed out the right problem .

Comment: What is the value of those variables? Are you actually establishing a database connection before using mysql_real_escape?

Comment: the values are string i am retrieving info of a youtube video .

Comment: friends wanted to confirm i goot it working by using  if($title=='undefined'||$thumbnail=='undefined'||$link=='undefined')  is it ok to use such ? like using the word undefined?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to do not use empty, cause it got some specific behave.

Second: I don't get why you are using mysql_real_escape_string, you have to query a database?

Moreover i guess you (as @havelock pointed out) wanted to get a 404 if none of that values are set up.

I'm for this:

```
if($title && $thumbnail && $link){
    //all fine..
}
else 404
```

Comment: This changed logic is exactly the same, only expressed in reverse.

Comment: what does it mean is not working? (@deceze i'm just not using the "empty". Can you kindly print_r or var_dump the 3 variables you are checking in that if?

Comment: @Gianps i got it working by using  if($title=='undefined'||$thumbnail=='undefined'||$link=='undefined') is it ok to use such or not ?

Comment: @SakshiSharma: remove that mysql_real_escape_string, why are you using that?

Comment: because its a youtube link it contains spaces and all and if it contains "" then the insert query does not work as there is extra "" in the value

Comment: using hte word undefined is wrong ot is it ok can you please tell me as this is working perfectly

Comment: if youtube api tells you that will return "undefined" when something is not defined so it's ok.. but i think this is kinda weird to me.

Comment: i am using embdly to get data of a youtube link . and its returning undefined if a link is not valid . so cant do nythn in that , its also weird to me but using undefined is working ? should i use it ?